# Selenium. HtmlUnitDriver. How to enable JavaScript and Cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies, selenium, webdriver, htmlunit-driver

This is an error I get when I try to navigate to page, using HtmlUnitDriver:

> JavaScript and Cookies need to be supported in order to use the site.
>   To be able to use all of the site's functions, download and install one of the following browsers

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get(url);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on JavaScript just by passing in `true` to the constructor. By Default JavaScript is `false` so you have to use following code for the same:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
driver.get(url);
```

Comment: Tried this, but I still get broken HTML...some of the page content is in "noscript" tags. This means that JavaScript doesn't support some of the sites features? any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

or

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
```